# Format grep command to have better display

Tags: linux, grep

```
grep -o . (some File) | sort -f| uniq -ic
```

i want to know if there is a way to make the display of this look better.
what this command displays

```
1 a
1 b
2 c
```

what i want it to look like

```
1 = a
1 = b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use awk like this:

```
grep -o . (some File) | sort -f| uniq -ic | awk '{$1=$1." ="; print $0}
```